# Google drive API folder search return inconsistent result

Tags: java, google-drive-api

When I search for folder using the following code, the folder is sometime found and sometime not.  Does anyone else has experienced this or there is an issue with my search query?

```
    private static final String SPACES = "drive";
    private static final String FIELDS = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
    private static final String FOLDER_MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
String query =
            "mimeType='" + mimeType + "' and trashed = false and name = '" + name + "' and '" + parentFolderId
                + "' in parents";
        LOG.info("Searching Google folder : {} ", query);
        FileList result = googleDriveClient.files().list().setQ(query).setSpaces(SPACES).setFields(FIELDS).execute();
```

I ran test scripts to recreate the problem.  The tests always works.  But when deployed to server I see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, know that this endpoint, like most others in the Google API suite produce paginated responses.  You are implicitly getting the first *page-worth*.

Without an order by clause, the server is at liberty to return results in any order, and so I suppose you must be getting a different first *page-worth*.

So first thing add `setOrderBy(..)`...

```
FileList result = googleDriveClient.files()
   .list()
   .setQ(query)
   .setSpaces(SPACES)
   .setFields(FIELDS)
   .setOrderBy("createdTime")
   .execute();
```

... and then your results should stabilise.  Then to page through your results you need to issue further queries passing in `pageToken` - see example here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In my query I specified the folder name with the parent folder where search should be done.  If the folder is there, the page should always contain the searched folder, no?